# Jenkins Restrict Where This Project Can Run From Properties File

Tags: file, jenkins, build, properties, restrict

I want to restrict a downstream Jenkins job to run on a specific machine using a parameter passed in from an upstream job.  The upstream job creates a properties file, with one of those properties indicating the machine it should run on (MACHINE_TO_RUN=linux123 in test.properties).

This file with all the properties is passed into my downstream job using Post-build Action: Trigger parameterized build on other projects.  Here I specify Parameters from properties file: $WORKSPACE/test.properties

I have verified that the downstream job does indeed receive and process the file.  MACHINE_TO_RUN=linux123 is listed in my environment variables.

How do I use this env variable to restrict where the job can run.  I've tried setting the "Restrict where this project can be run" to ${MACHINE_TO_RUN}, but no luck.

Anyone have any experience doing this?

---

UPDATE: Here is how I implemented this.

Download https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Label+Assignment+plugin

Build parameters are bound with this plugin.  So if you pass a cloud id or node into the job, for instance MACHINE_TO_RUN.

The plugin will let you write a groovy script that will let you return where you want the job to run.

return MACHINE_TO_RUN;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implemented something very much alike in the morning with [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin). So, you "parametrize" the downstream job with an extra parameter of "Label" type (available only after you installed the plugin mentioned above) and provide a value for this parameter from whatever source you have (test.properties file in your case).

Also you do not have to deal with "Restrict where this project can be run" setting anymore for the downstream job.

For example, lets say you have two jobs "BUILD" and "TEST" in Jenkins with the following definitions (using Groovy-alike pseudo-code):

```
[TEST]
  parameters: { targetNode: typeof(Label), defaultValue: '' }

[BUILD]
  parameters: {}

  set-env-variables: { from: './test.properties' } // or your way to set env vars

  trace-env-variable: { variable: $MACHINE_TO_RUN } // linux123

  post-build: {
     trigger: {
       job: "TEST", parameters: { targetNode: $MACHINE_TO_RUN }
     }
  }
```

That is pretty much what you need to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to parameterize the label expression in "Restrict where this project can be run" using environment variables but didn't make it.

I would like to recommend you:

- After the regular build step of your upstream job, create another build step to "Process Job DSLs"
- Use a groovy script to create the downstream job, by doing this, you can set up the "Restrict where this project can be run" in that groovy script.

You can take a look at the [Jenkins DSL Doc](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) and try to write a groovy script for creating your downstream job

Suck a groovy script will look like:

```
// You have to have MACHINE_TO_RUN as your environment variable in your upstream job
def machine_to_run=${MACHINE_TO_RUN} 
job(your_downstream_job_name) {
    label(machine_to_run)
    parameters {
        //The parameter setting of your downstream job
    }
    steps {
        //The build step of your downstream job 
    }
    //Other settings of your downstream job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it with [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

So, In my case, I was using a multjob project to invoke a free-style project. Multi-job projects are quite good as they can run sub projects in parallel. Ensure that, you just pass the node-name parameter from the multijob and it automatically takes care that the subproject is executed in the given node. Labels are also valid node-name parameters.

In this case, I didnt have to mess with `groovy`.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Alright guys, I have added more explanation now. Please remove your `down vote`